# ¿Como evitar la perdida de informacion de un activity cuando voy a otro activity o pongo el boton de retroceder?

Tags: android-studio, activity, textview, contador

Buenas tardes amigos.
Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla en la que es básicamente un contador, tengo un `textview` y 2 botones, uno para sumar y otro para restar el valor que este en el `textview` pero pasa que normalmente está en 0, hago los conteos y llego a por ejemplo 2, pero si voy a otro **activity** o pongo el botón salir y vuelvo, vuelve a aparecer el 0 y no el 2, como hago para solucionar esto, se que tiene que ver con el ciclo de vida de una **activity** y he revisado muchos tutoriales utilizando el método `onsavedInstanceState` pero no sirve, he visto que hay uno de **onStop** y **onPause** pero la verdad no se como implementarlos, ¿Qué sugerencias me dan? o **¿Cómo podría arreglar esta situación?**
Gracias a todos

Comment: Agrega el código de las actividades.